# How to access name of file in FileList object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, input, material-ui

I'm trying to upload files and then send the filepath to an API in the backend to store into a database, but I'm having issues retrieving the filename from the FileList object that is created.

I have this code:

```
const RawForm = () => {
        const [filepath, setFilepath] = useState([])

        const handleUpload = (event) => {
               setFilepath([...filepath, event.target.files])
        }

        const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
               e.preventDefault()
               console.log(filepath)
               for (const file in filepath[0]){
                     console.log("files are: " + file)
               }
        
       return (
              <Upload onUpload={handleUpload}/>
              <Submit onSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
        )
  }
```

And I have 2 components Upload and Submit, where Upload is the upload button defined like this:
It takes as input an onUpload prop through which I pass a function that sets the files.

```
export default function Upload ({onUpload}) {
return (
    <div >
        <input
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            id="upload-raw-files"
            multiple
            type="file"
            onChange={onUpload}
            
        /> 
        <label htmlFor="upload-raw-files">
            <Button 
            variant="contained"
            component="span"
            size="large"
            className="Upload"
            startIcon={<UploadIcon />}
            sx={{
                
                width: '130px',
                height: '40px',
                background: '#5985F7',
                border: '3px solid #5985F7',
            }}
            >
            Upload
            </Button>
        </label>
        
    </div>
) 
}
```

I also have the submit component, which is simply a button through which I pass a function to submit forms

```
export default function Submit = ({onSubmit}) => {
return (
    <div >
        <Button 
        onClick={onSubmit}
        variant="contained"
        size="large"
        className="Submit"
        sx={{
            width: '130px',
            height: '50px',
            background: '#5985F7',
            border: '3px solid #5985F7',
            borderRadius: '25px',
        }}
        >Submit
        </Button>
    </div>
) 
}
```

When I upload 3 files and click submit, then inspect the console, I see that the FileList object looks like this:
[image: FileList Object]
But with the code I have, what gets printed to console is this:
[image: What is outputted]

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get access to the filename. Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried doing

```
for (const file in filepath[0]){
        console.log("files are: " + file[0].name)
    }
```

just to see if I could at least get the name of the first object, but that gives me `files are: undefined`.

Comment: Use `for...of` instead of `for...in`

Comment: I see, I'm not used to javascript syntax yet. Thank you for the response!